# How to edit citation style in CSL? or What citation style is this?

Tags: citation-style, ieee

**What Style is this?**

I'm trying to work on a bibliography for a paper that has to conform to an unspecified citation style. It's basically [the CEEA2016 style](https://ceea.ca/images/content/CEEA%202016%20Dalhousie/CEEA_AuthorGuide_v2016.pdf):

[image: Picture for quick reference]

I saw this great link when googling which seems awesome [[CLS](http://editor.citationstyles.org/searchByExample/)]. The problem is that the closest I could get was [IEEE with URL](http://editor.citationstyles.org/styleInfo/?styleId=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.zotero.org%2Fstyles%2Fieee-with-url) which is close in many respects one of the major issues is that the citation style I need uses full names and the IEEE style uses Initials and Last names (Sarah Jane vs S. Jane). Is there a style that is closer to what I'm looking for?

**How do I make this style?**

Alternatively is there any way to edit the IEEE with URL style to give me full names? I've tried listening to webinars and none of them seem to get into that in my scrubbing and I've even found this [primer](http://docs.citationstyles.org/en/stable/primer.html#author-date-author-styles) which seemed to hint towards it but then completely dropped the topic of author names in favor of authorship dates (presumably because it's a heading for citation not bibliography as I would eventually figure out).

Answer (score 2):

I was able to find part of the answer

## Out of Editor

Here are lines 81-96 or the original IEEE with URL csl file. I was unable to find out how to do it in the visual editor but I was digging around in the XML file itself and saw this:

```
  <macro name="author">
    <names variable="author">
      <name initialize-with=". " delimiter=", " and="text"/>
      <label form="short" prefix=", " text-case="capitalize-first"/>
      <substitute>
        <names variable="editor"/>
        <names variable="translator"/>
      </substitute>
    </names>
  </macro>
  <macro name="editor">
    <names variable="editor">
      <name initialize-with=". " delimiter=", " and="text"/>
      <label form="short" prefix=", " text-case="capitalize-first"/>
    </names>
  </macro>
```

removing the `initialize-with=". "` seems to have given me full names. After this it looks like the only aspects I would like to change is adding URL at the end. Workable for now but I would like to know how to edit the CSL file as it would be enormously helpful and faster than what I'm going to have to do with REGEX.

## In Editor

Knowing what I was looking for and knowing the way programmers like to think I was able to find a similar setting in the visual editor

[image: http://imgur.com/FJbqmnG]

Bibliography > Layout > author (macro) > Names > Name

In the name section below is the "Initialize with" option.